# How do you make a widget that uses data from mysql using php like the link below?

Tags: php, mysql, widget

I have a website that currently takes data from a mysql database and using php outputs a table and graphs. I would like to make widgets that export the tables and graphs so bloggers can copy and paste the widget code, but I don't really know how to do that. I have searched online and I only see widget makers that use html code..

Is there any information/website you guys can recommend that can help me make widgets like the link below from what I currently have?

http://widgets.freestockcharts.com/CustomizeInteractive.aspx?guid=ba77c4d8-c2c9-4a8c-972d-08d2ba866d17&w=250&h=250

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple.  The method that the site you link to uses is simply an `<iframe>`.

The method that I see more commonly is a simple JavaScript include, where the end script fires off `document.write()` to output the data to the page.  This isn't always ideal, but does work, and allows you to change more later.